Is there a way to stall a python command until previous has finished?
I have a python function:
def a_function():
     #do something

It takes a while to finish, How do I stop the next command in the while true loop from running until it finishes?
import time 
def a_function():
     #do something
while True:
   a_function()
   time.sleep(5)

Currently It just starts the function and starts the timer so the timer finishes before the function messing up my schedule for the function.

As written, time.sleep won't run until a_function completes or returns.

Your function either does nothing, or does something really quickly (or perhaps there's an error occurring), and the timer starts afterwards, since you added no code that would cause anything to run in parallel. The default behaviour of Python is to do one thing, complete it and then move on to the next - you have add specific code to do what you think is happening.

I didn't want to add my real code it's just boring long request 30+ that takes forever It justs goes into an infinite loop so I think the timer is over before the function finishes

You need to share an example that actually reproduces the problem you're asking about.

what you descrtibe is just how it works ... define a_function as print("start");sleep(20);print("done")  and you will see it print start, then done... then after 5 more seconds it will print start again

Python by default is single-threaded, and everything executes in order.
print("Hello")
time.sleep(1)
print("World")

'Hello' will print, then a second later 'World' will print.
What I was describing just can't happen, I was probably misinterpreting the issue.
